# Image won't appear on JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

This is my code:

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;

    public class SenzuView extends JFrame {
      JLabel label;
      public SenzuView(){
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("C:\\senzu.jpg");
        label = new JLabel("", image, JLabel.CENTER);
        this.add(label);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SenzuView();
    }
}
```

The problem is that the Frame opens but its empty and the image never appears
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that the file exists? The code shows the picture when I run it.

Comment: You may need to add the label to the `BorderLayout.CENTER` so that it's resized automatically. You can look at the JavaDoc for more information.

Comment: I'd also recommend using `ImageIO.read` to load the images over `ImageIcon` (directly), see [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the `getClass.getResource` because that way if you later wants to compile the project into a .jar file the images will come with the project or else they wont appear if you go along with the solution path you were originally starting on.

- Make a folder inside your package where your main class is located in. Preferably called 'res'
- Move your image to that package.
- Initialize the image icon like this:

  ```
  ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("res/senzu.jpg"))
  ```
- The following is an example of how I suggest you should have your `SenzuView` coded:

  ```
  public SenzuView(){
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("res/senzu.jpg"));
      label = new JLabel(image);
      this.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
      setVisible(true)
  }
  ```

I hope this solved it and gave you some other useful tips.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a folder in your project directory named **images**. Then give the path as this:

`ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("images/senzu.jpg");`

This will work.

If you need an absolute path then use

`C:/Program Files/workspace/Senzu/images/senzu.jpg`

Hope it solved your issue.

Comment: Why the downvote? I checked the code and it runs and displays the image. Please explain.

Comment: BTW - not the down voter (yet) but I cannot see how this answer adds anything useful towards a solution.

Comment: I checked with jpeg also, it works. And by not adding anything useful towards a solution means? I thought giving a answer which solves the issue was good enough. Thanks

Comment: *"..giving a answer which solves the issue"* It is obvious that **you** are confident these suggestions will provide a solution, but that does not make it true. The first suggestion is to strip the root drive from the path and make it relative. A complete drive + path is always more 'reliable' than a relative path. The second suggestion then goes back to suggesting a complete path that bears no resemblance to the original path or file name. How's that supposed to fix anything?

Comment: Thank you for the information sir. I'll will keep this in mind

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110662/discussion-between-mvk059-and-andrew-thompson).